How can I delete unused docker layer cache with GitHub Actions in Google Cloud Artifact Registry?
I've created GitHub Actions workflow that build and push docker images to Artifact Registry with docker/build-push-action and deploy to Cloud Run.
This is my Artifact Registry. The tagged package is deployed to Cloud Run.

Does anyone have a good idea to delete all unused or unreferred images in Artifact Registry in GitHub Actions?
I can delete them by hand on console or GCP web console, but I wanna automate it.
My idea was to list all images except those tagged "${GITHUB_SHA}", sorted by updated and delete them after tagged image appear.
gcloud container images list-tags "${BASE_IMAGE}" \
  --filter="NOT tags:${GITHUB_SHA}" --format="table(digest, tags)" | \
  tail -n +2 | \
  while read row
  do
    arr=($row)
    if [ ${#arr[@]} -eq 2 ]; then
      start="true"
    fi

    if [[ -v start ]]; then
      digest=${arr[0]}
      gcloud container images delete -q --force-delete-tags "${BASE_IMAGE}@sha256:$digest"
    fi
  done

But I couldn't list sorted by updated because all layer-cache images' timestamp are UNIX epoch (1970/01/01 00:00:00).
Docker Image Timestamp Issue
So sometimes gcloud container images delete try to delete not-unreferred images and GitHub Actions workflow fails with this error.
Manifest is still referenced by one or more parent images: ocarry-api/manifests/sha256:93eec65fc56910c8c8012a385e7769fae87885f6459bc8e1613855730ef07007: None

this is my part of GitHub Actions yaml
      - name: Build and push
        id: docker-build
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v6
        with:
          platforms: linux/amd64
          context: .
          push: true
          tags: ${{ env.IMAGE }}
          cache-from: type=gha
          cache-to: type=gha,mode=max
      - name: Deploy to Cloud Run
        id: deploy
        uses: google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun@v2
        with:
          service: /* my service id */
          image: ${{ env.IMAGE }}
          region: ${{ env.GCP_REGION }}
      - name: Clean up Container images
        run: |
          gcloud container images list-tags "${BASE_IMAGE}" \
          /* the shell script above continues */


What do you mean by unused docker layer cache? You mean Image versions? If so, have a look at this Stackoverflow Link. To delete all unused or unreferred images with GitHub Actions in Artifact Registry have a look at this Configure cleanup policies and link.

Sorry for lack of explanation, yes I mean unreferred images pushed by GitHub Actions to Artifact Registry. I will look at your link, thank you.

Please edit the question by sharing detailed steps or the document, that anyone can use to replicate the behavior? Also share logs from the console by editing your question? Have you gone through the above shared links? For deleting the unused or unreferred images in Artifact Registry you need to configure the Cleanup policies or have a look at this Stackoverflow Link.
